# Trying to use Bluetooth in App, getting error

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm getting this error:

```
 Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
 Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
 The following classes could not be found:

 - application (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
 - manifest (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

and this is my code:

```
  < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
  < manifest

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <application >
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  < /manifest>
```

Comment: question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is below layout.

```
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```